# Is wrapping API calls a decent mechanism to abstract a common API

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a legacy javascript project that needs to use the same API, we are replacing some components with a different library and trying to make it seamless for the end user of the library.

That is for instance our old API has something like

```
$.grid({
     data:hdsds,
     url:dhshdas,
     // etc...
});
```

So now on the newGrid we want to have the same API

```
$.newGrid({
     data:hdsds,
     url:dhshdas,
     // etc...
});
```

but of course the two are not actually equal, so am thinking about adding wrapper methods that simply call the underlying grid for instace the grid would be

```
$.newGrid({
     dataSource:hdsds,
     location:dhshdas,
     // etc...
});
```

and we would map the data -> dataSource and url -> locaton, etc... does this seem like a proper way of doing things to create these wrapper methods, I've used this ind of mechanism in the past in C++ code but I wonder of there is a better way of doing this in JavaScript.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: What do you mean by saying "*have the same API*" but "*not actually equal*"?

Comment: Well give it the same method name but the implementation is not actually the same. so end users change just the name of components grid -> newGrid but not the parameters.